# How does dungeon world combat work?

Tags: combat, dungeon-world

I don't understand what dice I'm supposed to roll or anything. Do I roll my damage dice? I've never actually played a tabletop RPG so this'll be my first, so I guess my confusion is understandable.

Comment: Unless my ignorance of DW is making me miss something, this appears to be asking for a rules dump. Can I suggest reading the rules and then coming back here if you have specific questions?

Comment: Howdy, JoshTheNoob1776, and welcome to the site. Quick question: have you read the *Dungeon World* rulebook? I ask, because there's a whole chapter on how combat works, and most of the rest is spelled out on your playbook. Once you've done that, if you've got more questions, feel free to ask them.

Comment: I'm playing with a group that has never played before. Also I found the section for combat, but it still doesn't explain what dice to roll. Like for hack and slash moves it says "roll+STR" but not WHAT to roll.

Comment: @JoshTheNoob1776 Again, this is explained in the rules. You have to read the whole game before you can make the game work. What the "roll" part in "roll+STR" means is covered earlier—you can't skip around. If you missed something as important as that (and it's very important!), you've probably missed many important things about the game. Even if we explained what the "roll" part means, you're still going to be missing 99% of how to make the game (never mind just combat) work. Read the book—it's actually designed to teach you what you're asking us.

Comment: If you get through the rulebook and still don't quite 'get it' then [this guide](http://www.curufea.com/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=roleplaying:dw:dungeon_world_guide_pdf_version_1.2.pdf) might help. I know it helped me understand how Dungeon World is meant to work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are confused because you dice twice for a hack'n'slash:
1) dice 2d6+STR so see if the attack works out at all, i.e. if you hit.
2) dice your characters damage dice, e.g. 1d10 for a fighter.

For further information read the core rulebook, watch some youtubed livestreams of people playing the game, and join a hangout game via the dungeon world tavern (that´s the name of a google+ group).

Don´t worry, playing DW can be learen in an hour or two.

Comment: What parts of the core rulebook? What does get handled? This sounds adequate in the areas of recognising what's going on (probably) and providing guidance for study and learning, but is lacking in the department of explaining what they should do. How does combat work, can you talk about that? What pages should they investigate for the information they're after?

Comment: @doppelgreener I think the intention is "*all* the rulebook", hence leaving "where" unsaid. Combat is the deepest niche of the game's rules, and the GM has to grasp every layer above it before being able to run even a simple combat.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yeah, now that I notice the comments on the question that seems clear. :D

Answer (score 0):

The standard roll for Dungeon World is 2d6. When the system asks you to Roll+(a value), you roll 2d6 and add the relevant value. For example, when you are told to "roll+STR", you roll 2d6 and add your Strength Modifier.

For melee combat, the basic move is "Hack and Slash", which reads as follows:

---

When you attack an enemy in melee, roll+Str. 
✴On a 10+, you deal your damage to the enemy and avoid their attack. At your option, you may choose to do +1d6 damage but expose yourself to the enemy’s attack.
✴On a 7–9, you deal your damage to the enemy and the enemy makes an attack against you.

---

So basically, you roll 2d6+Str. If you get a 10 or higher, you hit. If you get a 7-9, you hit, but the enemy hits you too. If you get a 6 or lower you miss, and something bad usually happens (the enemy hits you, you drop your weapon, etc.)

Note that the GM and monsters don't really take actions like players do. The GM makes "moves" but mostly only in response to the players' missing or rolling the partial success on a 7-9.